# Using leanModal to show/hide forms that update my db, almost works perfectly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, modal-dialog

Without posting **all** of my code, I'm hoping I can figure out the last step to my leanModal PHP implementation of a basic CRUD system attempt.

So, this actually works, except for the last step. When I click submit on the form, somehow, it actually updates the database, but it doesn't reload the page, so the table-data still looks old, but if you manually reload the page, the table-data reflects the most recent update. Somehow, when submitting the form, the script that updates the database runs but the rest of the page doesn't load? I know I'm missing something, and maybe there's a better way of doing this...)

Hopefully, this is enough to give you an ideal what I'm doing. Thank you!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({
            closeButton: ".modal_close"
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
    //save
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $record = new Record();
        if(isset($_POST['id'])) { $record->id = mysql_prep($_POST['id']); }
        $record->name = mysql_prep($_POST['name']);
        $record->save();
    }
    //view
    $records = Record::find_all();
?>
<div id="table_data>
<table>
    <?php foreach($records as $record): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $record->name; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a rel="leanModal" href="#admin_form_<?php echo $record->id; ?>">edit</a>
                <div id="admin_form_<?php echo $record->id; ?>">
                    <form action="index.php?id=<?php echo $record->id; ?>" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $admin_nav->id; ?>">
                        <label for="name">Name</label><input name="name" id="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $record->name; ?>">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
                        <a class="modal_close" href="#"></a>
                    </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: After spending a few hours trying to make this work, I decided to abandon the concept in favor of a better solution: in-line table-data editing. I've actually got it running, except selects work, but are wonky, and checkboxes aren't working. Thanks for the advice. I really appreciate it, and even though I wasn't able to make it work, I learned something. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach i would suggest is create a separate route let's say `table.php` that will server just the table data.

In your case `table.php` will contain

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($records as $record): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $record->name; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a rel="leanModal" href="#admin_form_<?php echo $record->id; ?>">edit</a>
                <div id="admin_form_<?php echo $record->id; ?>">
                    <form action="index.php?id=<?php echo $record->id; ?>" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $admin_nav->id; ?>">
                        <label for="name">Name</label><input name="name" id="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $record->name; ?>">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
                        <a class="modal_close" href="#"></a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

and load is via ajax in your page in to `#table_data` div.

And call `leanModel` script after loading table.

And on submit of form just re-load your table data again. Load table script would look like this.

```
function load_table(){
    $.ajax('table.php', function(data){
        $('#table_data').html( data );

        // Call Lean Model Now
        $('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal({
            closeButton: ".modal_close"
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I'm going to give this a try. I'll report back :)

Comment: Ok, I implemented your suggestion but it's not loading my data. Should I put the function inside the document ready, or call it another way? Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I need my table data to load when the page first loads, before displaying any forms or submitting. The initial view shows all the records, then I click edit to bring up the form, submit, and the page **should** refresh.

Comment: Anyway, I made a separate table_data.php and made sure it worked by navigating straight to it. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Can you tel me what error you are getting. Use chrome console 'network panel' or firbug to see what kind of response you are getting.

Comment: Thank you @Vinay. I have moved on from this concept. I wasn't getting any errors, which is what made it so confusing. See my own comments on the OP. Thanks again.